# How to use C# client to consume Django/Python web service (all methods are returning null)?

Tags: c#, python, django, soap, wsdl

I have a C# command-line client that I'm testing the consumption of SOAP/WSDL via Django/Python/soaplib created WSDL. I've managed to successfully connect to the web service by adding a service reference. I then call one of service's methods, and the service processes the data I send, but it returns null instead of the integer I'm expecting. Any ideas on how to get back something other than a null response? Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: The most common reason for it returning null is that there is a type mismatch between the returned data type and what the c# proxy expects, for instance if the return message is any type of array of custom objects the soap specification must match **exactly** or it will render it as null. Can you put fiddler in between to watch the traffic between your proxy and the service to see what is being received?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is start by building a manual proxy using WebClient, or WebRequest/WebResponse. Construct your manual proxy to send the desired data to the WS for testing.

Couple of things to check on the WSDL implementation:

- The WSDL definition needs to match **exactly**, including case, for the C# proxy to recognize the values
- Namespace definitions need to match **exactly**, including trailing slashes
- Check the profile of the generated proxy and make sure it conforms with what your desired profile is (i.e. basic or none if needed)

If you post your generated proxy we can look at it and see if there is anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at all of that, but can't really figure out why it continues to return null. Unfortunately, I can't post the code, because its company property, but thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the similar problem while consuming a web service it was the type of data returned we were getting data in UTF-16 format.

Please check if you have proper data type in use.